# Why does Django upvote increases the vote of latest added item only?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

There is an upvote button in every item, but when I click it, it increases the upvote of the latest added item only.

```
<a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('upvote').submit() }">
<button  class="btn btn-success d-block w-100 mt-4"><span class="pull-left">UPVOTE <i
    class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> </span> <span class="pull-right"> {{product.upvote}} </span>
</button>
</a>
<form action="{% url 'upvote' product.id %}" method="POST" id="upvote">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="upvote">
</form>

from django.urls import path
from myApp import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('<int:product_id>/upvote',views.Upvote,name='upvote'),
]

def Upvote(request, product_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
        product.upvote += 1
        product.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Because in HTML, ids must be unique.

Comment: How can I make every item unique ?

Comment: Don't know because you haven't shown the rest of the template, but presumably there's a for loop going on so you could append the value of `product.id` or `forloop.counter` to the `upvote` ID in both places.

Comment: Why not bind the event on a class, write the element's ID to any data attribute, and read it from there?